# Firebase functions doesn't return set-cookies header

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I would like to know why when setting a set-cookie header in firebase functions, it doesn't show up on the browser's response headers when using the firebase tools emulator.

```
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer token')
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['__session=ninja'])
  res.end()
})
```

Comment: Typically you wouldn't want to set `Authorization` on a response (it belongs on the request) but I'm not sure why the cookie wouldn't get set. We *may* be stripping it and only allow client-set cookies, will have to investigate early next week.

Comment: Yeah I was testing it out. When using express' cookie-parser and cookie-session, what I get is this:

on firebase serve:
no cookies being set using res.cookie('__session') and no cookies being set using req.session.token = token

on firebase deploy
no cookies being set using res.cookie('__session') and cookies being set using req.session.token = token but it doesn't get read in req because firebase only allows '__session'.

Was trying to do a no js type of authentication on browser side for to make it progressive but I can't set it

Comment: Seems like Firebase emulator does not allow for cookies to be set. But when  deployed to Firebase hosting, cookies are set and work just fine

Answer (score 1):

Is this function a stand-alone function or are you integrating it with Firebase Hosting? I tried the following function:

```
exports.headers = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('X-Test', 'OK');
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['__session=ninja'])
  res.send('OK');
});
```

I saw both the x- and set-cookie headers in the response.

Comment: I integrated it with firebase functions. When deployed in firebase it works, but on local client (when using firebase serve), it doesn't. When i also use express js with firebase functions, it doesn't work both on deployed and local

Answer (score 0):

Also, you need to set Cache-control as private:

```
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'private');
```